# Trying to install Ubuntu on computer via cd; no bootable device

Tags: installation, dell, livedvd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my desktop computer, a Dell Inspiron 530, intel core 2 duo. I burned the DVD on my friends computer, it verified correctly, but when I try to boot from CD/DVD drive, it reads as follows:

```
BEGIN-------------BEGIN

Boot from CD:
No boot device available, Press ENTER key to retry
SATA-0: Installed
SATA-1: Installed
SATA-4: None
SATA-5: None

END----------------END
```

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key yeilds no results, I am stuck, and would like instruction as for how to proceed ?

If at all possible ?

Comment: have you checked if your hard disk is all ok?

Comment: did you choose `burn image` option while burning the iso on cd?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the computer and start hitting the F12 key. This will bring up the boot menu.

Choose the dvd drive. If it is not available Restart the computer hitting the F2 key This will boot to bios. Check your computer recognizes the dvd drive plus the hard drive you are going to install on.

Hope that helps
Larry Keenan